# How to specify portable jndi datsource lookup in grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, weblogic, datasource, jndi

I know JNDI lookup in grails is as simple as

```
datasource {
  jndiName = "java:comp/env/myDataSource"
}
```

this works great on Tomcat.

On other containers (WebLogic, JBOSS, etc.) the jndiName for the same thing would be just `myDataSource` . The question is how do I configure this to be generic and *portable* so that the code does not need to be changed based on the deploy target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to key off a system property that you know will be set when running in Tomcat and not set anywhere else, e.g.

```
datasource {
  jndiName = "${System.getProperty('catalina.home') ? 'java:comp/env/' : ''}myDataSource"
}
```

Comment: interesting idea! but isn't there a common straight forward way?

Comment: I used that solution for a while, and it worked good for distuingishing a Tomcat server vs a Weblogic server. But, I recently tried putting my Grails app on a Glassfish server and it doesn't work, because... I believe Glassfish also uses Catalina, so the expression does return a value. But Glassfish needs the naming to just be the "myDatasource" whereas Tomcat requires the whole "jav:comp/env/".

Comment: So I did this... not sure if the "best way", but I tested on Glassfish, Tomcat, and Weblogic and it does work for those:      jndiName = "${(System.getProperty('catalina.home') && (System.getProperty('java.class.path')).trim().toLowerCase().indexOf('tomcat') > 0 ) ? 'java:comp/env/' : ''}jdbc/myGrails"